# Moving between underscore separated words with Alt + ←/→ in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

In PyCharm when I move between words with the `Alt + ←/→` shortcut it moves the cursor between whitespace separated words. How can I make it move the cursor between `underscore_seperated_words`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The option is not obvious but if I tick `Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Use "CamelHumps" words` then when moving between words with `Alt + ←/→` I can step between underscore separated words rather than just space separated "words". *The same works for camelCase words obviously.*

Comment: Good answer. By the way, it _is_ [documented](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__CamelHumps.html) that CamelHumps works on underscore_names as well, but only if you already know where to look…

Comment: @abarnet Thanks for the link - I didn't realise that it meant you could also autocomplete based on the acronyms of your underscore separated words

Comment: One of my colleagues uses PyCharm, and every time I sit at her computer I find something new to impress me with how every feature is really thought through and made as consistent and general as possible. If underscore_names work like CamelCaseNames in one place, they do everywhere (or, if not, they will the next version after someone reports the bug). If only the same were even remotely true for Aquamacs plus my cobbled-together elisp collection…

Comment: I love this answer thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want both capabilities for whitespace separated and camelCase separated curser movement and selection, there are options in the keymap under `Editor Actions` called:

- `Move Caret to Next Word`
- `Move Caret to Next Word in Different "CamelHumps" Mode`
- `Move Caret to Next Word with Selection in Different "CamelHumps" Mode`
- `Move Caret to Pervious Word`
- `Move Caret to Previous Word in Different "CamelHumps" Mode`
- `Move Caret to Previous Word with Selection in Different "CamelHumps" Mode`

As I mainly use the regular cursor movement with `Ctrl + ←/→` I added `Alt + ←/→` for the `"CamelHumps"` mode. As mentioned, the CamelCase works for underline separated as well.